# How can I reverse the direction of an element on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make it so that when my 'Player' reaches a jumpDistance of 50, it falls down, so he makes a small ' jump ' .

The code might not be exactly "clean" at this point, but I'm getting started with Javascript.

I made the player jump by using a for loop with a delay. I tried to make him go down the same way, but this didn't work out the way I planned.

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcmyur3o/1/)**

**** NOTE : Press space to start!**

```html
 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <style>
     #canvas {
     background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 1);
     }

    </style>
    <body>
    <div>
    <p id="jumpDistance"></p>
    <p id="jumpDirection"></p>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var xPos = 150;
    var yPos = 375;
    var jumpDistance = 0;
    function spelerObj() {

        canvas.width=canvas.width;
        context.rect(xPos, yPos, 25, 25);
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 25, 25);
    }
    function jump(e) { //Here the player jumps, with a loop that calculates it's jump-distance.
        //alert(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {//
            function upLoop() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if(jumpDistance < 50) {
                        yPos -= 1;
                        jumpDistance++;
                        upLoop();
                        spelerObj();
                        document.getElementById("jumpDistance").innerHTML = jumpDistance.toString();


                    }
                }, 1)
            }


            upLoop();
            spelerObj();


        }
    }


    document.onkeydown = jump;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to bring the jumper down. Also, your jump function probably shouldn't be inside the if statement. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcmyur3o/2/)

Comment: *this didn't work out the way I planned* I don't know what that means. You'd probably want a `downLoop` function which mirrors the `upLoop` function, but does `yPos += 1;`. You might also want to look at [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) if you start to see jerkiness in the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a downloop that you can switch to at the top of the jump:

```
function upLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (jumpDistance < 50) {
            yPos -= 1;
            jumpDistance++;
            upLoop();
        } else {
            downLoop();
        }

        spelerObj();
        document.getElementById("jumpDistance").innerHTML = jumpDistance.toString();
    }, 1)
}

function downLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (jumpDistance > 0) {
            yPos += 1;
            jumpDistance--;
            downLoop();
        }

        spelerObj();
        document.getElementById("jumpDistance").innerHTML = jumpDistance.toString();
    }, 1)
}
```

**[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/gcmyur3o/3/)**

You could also vary the timeout duration to add a pseudo-gravity effect.

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/gcmyur3o/4/)**

Comment: Thanks alot, i'm new to Javascript and tried to make something simple for practice purposes.
Thanks to your Demo 1, i got it working, but it's still a bit wiggly. But i'll manage to proceed from here on! Thanks alot!